# Building CANoe dll from Simulink Model

Tags: matlab, simulink, canoe

I am trying to build Vector CANoe dll(shall be added in simulation node) from Simulink model. I have used MinGW compiler and Vector_AddOn_Matlab_Interface package for interface between CANoe and Simulink. My question is what is minimum matlab toolbox is needed for dll generation?

Thanks,
Varun

Answer (score 0):

The first page of the Application Note *Using MATLAB with CANoe* says:

> Currently all MATLAB versions starting with R2007b are supported

Comment: I have updated version of Matlab but I want to know which all toolboxes needed for dll generation so that I can purchase licenses separately.